# LPC1769 PC Communication

Tags: uart, cortex-m3, lpc

I am using [LPC1769](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/LPC1769_68_67_66_65_64_63.pdf) micro controller and planning to use one of its serial (UART) port for PC communication.

It has 4 UART ports (UART0,1,2 and 3)

For PC communication purpose, can I use all ports or there is limitation on specific port?

How to check which is suitable for PC communication?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are using NXPs LPCxpresso evaluation board for this, then the documentation that came with it should say which UART is connected to the debugger.  Otherwise you could use a simple UART to USB bridge.

Answer (score 3):

As far as the chip is concerned, you can use any UART port for any purpose you like.

However, if you are using a particular evaluation board or a particular software library, these may impose additional limitations. You'll have to read the documentation associated with each.

Comment: Can I use any uart port for flash programming on serial port?

Comment: That would depend on the flash programming firmware (a.k.a. "bootloader"). Again, read the documentation.